# SQL Where based on other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SKU STORE DAY INVENTORY(start of day) DEMAND RECEIPTS
1   x     1   5                         10      9
1   x     2   =5-10+9
```

I am trying to forecast inventory levels based on inventory levels, demand and inventory receipts of the prior day. I need it to be robust enough for a database with many unique store-sku-day combinations.

E.g.

```
UPDATE table
SET inventory=inventory(prior day)+receipts(prior day)-demand(prior day)
```

This is in Microsoft SQL

What would be the correct SQL code to achieve this?

Comment: Robust? Can You provide a robust question format first, please?

Comment: Where is there any `where` here?

Comment: what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: So... you have one day for each store-sku-day combination with `INVENTORY, DEMAND, RECEIPTS` data, and you want to add row with next day with data in `INVENTORY` based on a prior day? Or you need some kind of update of every row for each day based on prior day?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE TBL
SET inventory = (PriviosDay.inventory + PriviosDay.receipts - PriviosDay.demand)
FROM (SELECT [DAY] + 1, inventory, receipts, demand) AS PriviosDay
WHERE
    TBL.[DAY] = PriviosDay.[DAY]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have approached this in the past is as follows.  First you want a table that one row for every store, then a table with one row for every sku.  Then you have a transaction table with one row for every reciept and one row for every reduction.  This way you have the data needed to determine what an inventory level was at any point in time.

Next you create a view that joins the data from the tables above and takes an optional parameter of date, if populated it will tell you the inventory level on that particular day.  You could make that datetime if you want to get that precise.

The view for current inventory would look something like this.

```
Select I.SKU, Store, Reciepts - Demand TotalInventory
   From Items I
   Join Transactions T On T.ItemID = I.ID
   Join Store S On S. = T.StoreID
   Where T.Date <= @DateParameter  -- This gives endof day, < gives end of previous day.
   Group By I.SKU, S.Store
```

Of course inventory systems can get much more complex, this is just a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using window functions. It assumes the oldest record (lowest *day* value) for a given store has the *inventory* value correctly set: it is the starting point to cascade the calculated value from there to all next records. All other stored *inventory* values are ignored in the calculation.

Then the update only updates the *inventory* value when it is different from the calculated value. So if all is already correct, nothing gets updated.

The query has a sub query (*calc*) which does the inventory calculation, taking the initial *inventory* of the store, adding all (*receipts* - *demand*) to it, up to, but not including, the current record's day.

Note that this will work also if there are gaps in the day sequences.

```
update t
set    inventory = calc.inventory
from   (select sku,
               first_value(inventory) over (
                   partition by store
                   order by day
                   rows unbounded preceding)
               + sum(receipts-demand) over (
                   partition by store
                   order by day
                   rows unbounded preceding)
               + demand - receipts as inventory
        from   t) as calc 
where  t.sku = calc.sku
and    (t.inventory is null or t.inventory <> calc.inventory);
```

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e905e/1).

Note that I had to do the fiddle on the Postgres engine as the SQL Server engine is mostly unavailable. But for this query the syntax is the same as for SQL Server ([SQL:2008](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql/) compliant syntax).